# Android - Build Failed error While Running an App

Tags: android

I am Using `Android Studio 4.0` when i run my `Hello App` it shows the following `gradle` Error

```
`Build-tool 30.0.1 is missing AAPT at C:\Users\karthickyuvan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.1\aapt.exe
Build-tool 30.0.1 is missing AAPT at C:\Users\karthickyuvan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.1\aapt.exe

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Installed Build Tools revision 30.0.1 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
`
```

Comment: `Installed Build Tools revision 30.0.1 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager`

Comment: i want to uncheck the 30.0 in sdk and i want to install again ? @Basi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended this is Go to Sdk Manager and uninstall 30.0 and install again

To fix temporary for the current Running project use

Android SDK Build-Tools is a component of the Android SDK required for building Android apps. It's installed in the /build-tools/ directory.

You should always keep your Build Tools component updated by downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager. If you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the plugin specifies. To use a different version of the build tools, specify it using buildToolsVersion in your module's build.gradle, as follows:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    ...
```

Comment: We keep getting it intermittently :( and not sure why in CI jobs.  Our buildToolsVersion matches the 30.0.1 in the error we get too.